# How to deep update two values inside Immutable Js Map in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, updates, immutable.js

I am trying to update two(`width` & `x`) values inside `items` -> `yrgroih9` as given below:

```
{
  appElements: {
    layers: {
      layer_1: {
        background: {
          width: '100px',
          height: '100px',
          bgColor: '#aaaaaa',
          bgImage: 'http:bgimage1.png'
        },
        items: {
          yrgroih9: {
             width: '100px',
             x: '200px',
             y: '200px'
           },
           qhy0dukj: {
             width: '100px',
             x: '200px',
             y: '200px'
           },
           '7lw2nvma': {
             width: '100px',
             x: '200px',
             y: '200px'
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Code used to update new object inside** `items`-> `yrgroih9`:

```
case 'UPDATE_OBJECT':
  return state.setIn(["appElements","layers","layer_1","items","yp57m359"],{
    ["width"]: action.objData.width,
    ["x"]: action.objData.x
  });
```

The above code removes `y` key inside the current location `yrgroih9` and updates the `width` and `x` values.

Redux store data arranged after setIn: (from chrome redux devtools):
[image]

How to **update two deep values without removing the other key values.?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn).

If your items are instances of Immutable.js Map:

```
case 'UPDATE_OBJECT':
  return state.updateIn(['appElements', 'layers', 'layer_1', 'items', 'yrgroih9'],
    (item) => item
      .set('width', action.objData.width)
      .set('x', action.objData.x)
  );
```

If your items are plain JS objects:

```
case 'UPDATE_OBJECT':
  return state.updateIn(['appElements', 'layers', 'layer_1', 'items', 'yrgroih9'],
    (item) => ({
      ...item,
      width: action.objData.width,
      x: action.objData.x,
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

state.setIn replace the whole object in the path you have given (appElements -> layers -> layer_1 -> items -> yp57m359). You can get an existing object, modify fields and then use setIn:

```
const oldObject =
 state.hasIn(["appElements","layers","layer_1","items","yp57m359"])
   ? state.getIn(["appElements","layers","layer_1","items","yp57m‌​359"])
   : {};
const newObject = {
  ...oldObject,
  width: action.objData.width,
  x: action.objData.x
};
return state.setIn(["appElements","layers","layer_1","items","yp57m359"], newObject);
```

Comment: Your code shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layers' of undefined` in the first line itself

Comment: Ok, it's because you don't have appElements in your state initially. Try to check if it is there (state.hasIn(["appElements", "layers", ....])) and if not just assign oldObject to empty (oldObject = {})

Comment: @ArunValaven I've updated the answer to check whether value exists.

Comment: Hmm.. Try state.getIn(["appElements","layers","layer_1","items","yp57m359"]) instead of state.appElements.layers.layer_1.items.yp57m359

Comment: Also tried getIn which adds irrelevant arrays:  
vsize
_root-> ownerID
entries -> entries[0]->["100x","width"]
entries[1]->["200x","width"]
entries[2]->["200x","width"]
__altered
width
x
inside "yp57m‌​359" key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154143/discussion-between-arunvalaven-and-hypuk).